# Get substring after penultimate space in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I had a pretty similar question, but this case is more complicated, and it probably could be helpful for someone.

Is it also possible to get first substring after penultimate space? 
'Viatti V-130 Strada Asimmetrico 215/60 **R16** 95V' - get R16
'Viatti Vettore Brina V-525 205/70 **R15C** 106/104R' - get R15C

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "(.+) "), "([^ ]+)$")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your data to process is in A2:A, this should do it:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"(\S+)\s\S+$")))`